# How to write a sql query to get following result?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get attachment post ids (post_id) from Wordpress wp_postmeta table which not associated as thumbnail for a post.

currently I'm getting all the attachments using below query

```
select * from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
```

which gives results like below

[image]

then I'm getting posts which already have a attachment using below query

```
select * from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
```

which gives results like below

[image]

by comparing these results, I'm getting the unattached files

which are these highlighted rows

[image]

Instead of running two queries and comparing it using PHP, is there way to get a result i wanted using a one MySQL query? if so any help would be appreciated

Regards

Comment: You want only those records whose thumbnail is missing, am I right?

Comment: add to the `WHERE` clause

Comment: add `left join` clause before `where` clause

Comment: @1000111 yes i want those records

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
select t1.* from wp_postmeta t1 where t1.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND t1.post_id NOT IN (select t2.meta_value from wp_postmeta t2 where t2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
```

Notice that this query has performance issues because of nested query.